# Angular 2 - ReferenceError: 'CustomType' is not defined - error only in one module

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, typelite

I have an Angular 2 CLI app with multiple lazy loaded modules. As the backend I am using a .NET API that exports its models via [TypeLite](http://type.litesolutions.net/). The problem I have is that in one module the type definitions work fine but in the other module I get a reference error when I browse to the module.

The referenced types work perfectly inside the media module, but not inside the location module. I have no idea why and can't find any hint on where to search for the error.

The app compiles without errors when using angular-cli. But as soon as I browse or reference the location module I get the following error:

```
error_handler.js:60 Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: TapeManager is not defined
ReferenceError: TapeManager is not defined
    at Object.1477 (location-details.component.ts:2)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 3623bc1…:52)
    at Object.1452 (2.chunk.js:15)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 3623bc1…:52)
    at . async:27
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:242)
    at Object.onInvoke (ng_zone.js:271)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:241)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:113)
    at zone.js:535
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:275)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (ng_zone.js:262)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:274)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:151)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:433)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:501) [angular]
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:486) [angular]
    at vendor.bundle.js:174453:17 [angular]
    at Object.onInvokeTask (ng_zone.js:262) [angular]
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:274) [angular]
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:151) [<root> => angular]
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:433) [<root>]
```

This is how the failing component looks like:

```
import {Component, OnInit, Input} from "@angular/core";
import Location = TapeManager.Models.Locations.Location;

@Component({
  selector: 'tm-location-details',
  templateUrl: './location-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./location-details.component.scss']
})
export class LocationDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  location: Location;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

I have an other component inside the media module that has exactly the same reference to the `Location` model but throws no error:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import {MediaService} from "./media.service";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
import {MdSnackBar} from "@angular/material";
import Media = TapeManager.Models.Mediae.Media;
import Location = TapeManager.Models.Locations.Location;

@Component({
    selector: 'app-media',
    templateUrl: './media.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./media.component.scss'],
    providers: [MdSnackBar]
})
export class MediaComponent implements OnInit {

    public mediae: Observable<Media[]>;
    public location: Location;

    constructor(public mediaService: MediaService) {

    }

    ngOnInit(): void {

        this.mediae = this.mediaService.getEntities();
    }
}
```

The app-routing.module looks like this:

```
  {
    path: 'location',
    loadChildren: 'src/app/+location/location.module#LocationModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'media',
    loadChildren: 'src/app/+media/media.module#MediaModule'
  },
```

The referenced typings look like this and are located inside `src/typings` which is referenced in the tsconfig under the type roots.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "",
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es7", "dom" ],
    "mapRoot": "./src/",
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
      "src/typings"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "dist",
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Here is a sample of the type definitions generated by TypeLite:

```
/// <reference path="Enums.ts" />
...
declare module TapeManager.Models.Locations {
    interface Address extends TapeManager.Models.Common.Entity {
        additionalInformation: string;
        city: string;
        country: TapeManager.Models.Locations.Country;
        formattedAddress: string;
        postalCode: string;
        state: string;
        street: string;
        streetNumber: string;
    }
    interface Coordinate {
        latitude: number;
        longitude: number;
    }
    interface Country extends TapeManager.Models.Common.Entity {
        active: boolean;
        alphaCode: string;
        name: string;
        numericCode: number;
    }
    interface Location extends TapeManager.Models.Common.Entity {
        address: TapeManager.Models.Locations.Address;
        coordinates: TapeManager.Models.Locations.Coordinate;
        name: string;
    }
    interface LocationHistory extends TapeManager.Models.Common.Entity {
        checkedIn: Date;
        checkedInBy: TapeManager.Models.Users.Principal;
        checkedInById: string;
        checkedOut: Date;
        checkedOutBy: TapeManager.Models.Users.Principal;
        checkOutById: string;
        location: TapeManager.Models.Locations.Location;
        media: TapeManager.Models.Mediae.Media;
    }
}
...
```

What am I doing wrong? Whats responsible for the error and how can I fix it?

Comment: @Siluthus you got any Solution for your Problem ?